# Installing plug ins on a wordpress hosted site

Tags: plugins, installation

I'm looking to use my wordpress site as a form to collect information from customers (no need for e-commerce).

I have found a great free plug in (Form Maker) but it doesn't give me an install opion. My domain is currently wordpress hosted (gbrooksey.wordpress.com).

Will buying my own domain and hosting it on wordpress alleviate this problem?

Teaching myself this whole website so any onsite would be greatly appreciated. Really trying to avoid buy the premium as its not needed at this time for my small business.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to contact wordpress.com and speak to them about options. Self hosted sites on the other hand gives you much more flexibilty  but it does come at some cost like buying a domain name and hosting. And when bying hosting, you would want a good host which does not come cheap

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to install any plugins on WordPress.com. In order to do that you'll need to move to the self-hosted version of WordPress that you can download for free at WordPress.org.

You will need to purchase hosting and domain. Some hosts can have WordPress setup for you as part of their hosting package.

I use [SiteGround](https://www.siteground.com/) and quite like them. There are other equally as good options for hosting our there as well - my only recommendation is to go with one that specializes in WordPress.

Good luck!